# Achieving row index functionality in JPA Criteria API

Tags: java, sql, jpa, criteria-api

So I have the following situation: two joint entities, Offer and Item, where I want to fetch parts and put them into a tuple object like that:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
Metamodel m = entityManager.getMetamodel();
EntityType<Offer> offerMeta = m.entity(Offer.class);

CriteriaQuery<MyTupleContainer> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(MyTupleContainer.class);
Root<Offer> offer = criteriaQuery.from(Offer.class);
Join<Offer, Item> item = offer.join(offerMeta.getSingularAttribute("item", Item.class));

criteriaQuery.multiselect(offer.get("id"), item.get("name"), offer.get("offerValidUntil"),
item.get("regularPrice"), offer.get("discountInPercent"));
```

Afterwards, filtering, sorting and pagination gets applied (the data is presented in a table).

This works fine as it is, however I ALSO want to fetch the index of each element *when default sorting and no filtering / pagination is applied!* Specifically, default order is by `offer.get("offerValidUntil")`, ascending. So if my database table has 100 entries, I want them to dynamically get indices 1 to 100 at query execution, and custom sorting / filtering / pagination should be applied afterwards (because obviously it would mess up the correct mapping if done afterwards).

I have a working SQL query that does what it should with the help of the `ROW_NUMBER` Oracle window function:

```
SELECT Offer.id AS id, 
 Item.name AS name,
 Offer.offer_valid_until AS offerValidUntil,
 Item.regular_price AS regularPrice,
 Offer.discount_in_percent AS discountInPercent
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY Offer.offer_valid_until ASC) AS listIndex
 FROM Offer LEFT JOIN Item ON Item.id = Offer.item_id
```

What's the best way to do it with the Criteria API?

Thanks in advance!